# how to assign variable in this jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a few divs

```
<div number='one_one' />
<div number='one_two' />
<div number='one_three' />
```

in jquery variable i have

```
var session_one = "one_one";
```

my problem is i cant click programatically the div with that number attribute
here is my trying :

```
$("div[number=session_one]").click()
```

but instead of click i have got an Object

```
Object[]
```

please help

Comment: You're looking for string concatenation.

Comment: `$("div[number=" + session_one + "]").click()`

Comment: Also, you need to delegate a click event in order to call `click()` programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate it like bellow

```
$("div[number=" + session_one + "]").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div[number='"+session_one+"']").trigger("click");
```

You are checking session_one with div number. But there is no div with number session_one. So you have to pass your div number as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Use: `$("div[number=" + session_one + "]").click()`

FYI: I wouldn't use the property "number" in a div. Use "id" or at least "data-number" which is html5 valid.

Answer (score 1):

i think its because `number` is not a valid `HTML Attribute` use HTML5 data attribute as

```
<div data-number='one_one' />
<div data-number='one_two' />
<div data-number='one_three' />
```

then jquery

```
var session_one = "one_one";
$("div[data-number=" + session_one + "]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax should be like this:

```
$("div[number="+session_one"+]").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

If you want to trigger it automatically, use this:

```
$("div[number="+session_one"+]").trigger("click");
```